# How to add Buttons and a background on GamePanel

Tags: android

My game's `MainActivty` set content view to a `GamePanel` that extends `SurfaceView` and Implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. How do i add buttons and set the background for the game? I tried adding buttons through xml but it only shows blackscreen.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a surface view you are basically taking over responsibility for rendering the entire view.

So you implement a bunch of rendering routines and override onDraw( Canvas canvas )

Too render a background you would do something like this and call it from onDraw

```
private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas) {


    Paint paint= getPaintForBackground();


    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);
}

 private Paint getPaintForBackground() {

    String key = "BACKGROUND";

    Paint paint = mapPaints.get(key);

    if (paint == null) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(symbolColor);
        paint.setAlpha(50);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);


        mapPaints.put(key, paint);
    }

    return paint;


}
```

You also render buttons and state changes in a similar fashion.

You can use an OnTouchListener to detect press state and color the 
approriate button state changes.